# Get Tor and Irssi working together

Tags: 10.10, proxy, tor, irssi

Hi I am trying to get Tor working with Irssi.

The directions at the bottom of this page [Freenode Install Link](http://freenode.net/irc_servers.shtml#tor)
say to

```
:~/.irssi$ tor MapAddress 10.40.40.40 p4fsi4ockecnea7l.onion
Feb 12 04:26:51.101 [notice] Tor v0.2.1.29 (r318f470bc5f2ad43). This is experimental software. Do not rely on it for strong anonymity. (Running on Linux x86_64)
Feb 12 04:26:51.101 [warn] Command-line option 'p4fsi4ockecnea7l.onion' with no value. Failing.
Feb 12 04:26:51.101 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

Or add it to the torrc file and reload irssi

```
.irssi$ cat /etc/tor/torrc  |grep 10.40.40
mapaddress  10.40.40.40  p4fsi4ockecnea7l.onion
```

This is a paste from within irssi after running `$torify irssi`

```
[04:33] Math::BigInt: couldn't load specified math lib(s), fallback to Math::BigInt::FastCalc at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Crypt/DH.pm line 6
[04:33] 
[04:33] *** Irssi: Loaded script cap_sasl
```

So I thought it was a CPAN module issue.

```
cpan[1]> install Math::BigInt
```

This was also done for FastCalc and retried with force install.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: This question is also in superuser.com: http://superuser.com/questions/244927/tor-irssi-ubuntu-10-10

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards